# Admin Grid add column

Tags: admin, grid

I added a column to the admin grid, to filter on a custom attribute.
But this filter does not work properly.

When I filter on value "50" it also display all values with "150".
How can I change that?

I use this admin grid code:

```
    $this->addColumn('type_staffel', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('type_staffel'),
        'width' => 100,
        'index' => 'type_staffel',
    ));
```

Comment: is type_staffel number?

Comment: @Abdul What do you mean with is number?

Comment: add 'type'  => 'number' to filter with range value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define your column like this:

```
$this->addColumn('type_staffel', array(
    'header' => $helper->__('type_staffel'),
    'width'  => 100,
    'index'  => 'type_staffel',
    'type'   => 'number'
));
```